# Do not save command into history when $pwd under specific folder?

Tags: zsh, command-history

I use zsh for autocompletion and history, it served very well but command history sometime filled with unwanted entries that for example, I do many task under folder `movies` ..etc, moving file, rename ..etc that shouldn't be in history command at all.

Is there away to avoid that issue and exclude command history saving under some specific folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you could use the `zshaddhistory` hook function to override the default "save history" behavior:

```
zshaddhistory() {
  case $PWD in
    (*/movies) return 1;;
    (*)        return 0;;
  esac
}
```

See `man zshmisc` for the description, which says, for the zshaddhistory function:

> Executed when a history line has been read interactively, but before it is executed.  The sole argument is the complete history line (so that any terminating newline will still be present).
>
> If any of the hook functions return a non-zero value the history line will not be saved, although it lingers in the history until the next line is executed allow(ing) you to reuse or  edit it immediately.

Comment: Thanks but does `(*/movies)` will exclude recursively all folder under `movives/*`?

Comment: It will match if your current directory *ends* in `/movies`. It would not match if your PWD is `.../movies/something`.

Comment: I specify a specific folder like `(/home/myuser/.cache/downloads)`, it doesn't work, is it must be wildcard `*`?

Comment: I tried to address what you asked in the question; I'm not sure what you mean with the downloads folder and what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: I had to comment other code in `zshaddhistory` that also has return, can we add multiple hook functions like `zshaddhistory` with other names?

Comment: Tuyen, I'm not expert at zsh's hooking functions, but the man page indicates the ability to create an array named, e.g. zshaddhistory_functions, containing a list of functions to execute; it will first execute zshaddhistory(), if it exists, then each of the functions in the ..._functions list. That seems to be the direction you're going.