# is there any way to invert history_ignore in zsh?

Tags: zsh, wildcards, command-history

I'm trying to invert or reverse the HISTORY_IGNORE parameter. Specifically trying to only include certain things in the history file, instead of selecting certain ones to exclude.

For example, if I were to only include only commands prefixed with "recordthis ", that exactly what I want.

I don't know if there's a way to use anything like HISTORY_INCLUDE, which doesn't exist as far as I know. I also don't know if there's a way to say `HISTORY_IGNORE="(*|!recordthis *)"`, which I think I tried, without desired results.

Comment: If you need more flexibility, you can use the [`zshaddhistory` hook](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/550712/do-not-save-command-into-history-when-pwd-under-specific-folder/550718?r=SearchResults&s=2|24.1168#550718)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HISTORY_IGNORE` is interpreted as a zsh wildcard pattern, so provided you set the `extendedglob` option, you can define

```
HISTORY_IGNORE='^recordthis*'
```

For `zsh` not to save entries that don't start with `recordthis` into `$HISTFILE`.

`^` is the negation glob operator. See also the `~` *except* (or *and-not*) operator (also requires `extendedglob`):

```
HISTORY_IGNORE='*~recordthis*'
```

(ignore *anything* (`*`) except strings starting with `recordthis`).